# If rows have repeated names only return the row with the repeat

Tags: sql, ms-access

To elaborate, say I have this table:

```
NAME  | ID | EMAIL       | TYPE
------+----+-------------+------
Joe   | 1  | NULL        | 01
Joe   | 1  | joe@email   | 02
Henry | 2  | NULL        | 01
Jane  | 3  | jane@email  | 01
Jane  | 3  | jane@email  | 02
Larry | 4  | larry@email | 01
Sue   | 5  | NULL        | 02
```

I want to return this:

```
Joe      |    1        |       joe@email    |   02
Henry    |    2        |         NULL       |   01
Jane     |    3        |      jane@email    |   02
Larry    |    4        |     larry@email    |   01
Sue      |    5        |         NULL       |   02
```

I've tried `Select Distinct` but that returns the original table. I have not found anything else that seems to tackle what I'm asking since the rows aren't total repeats, just the first two columns.

```
Select *
From Table_Name
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want the record from each person with the highest `TYPE` value.  One straightforward approach uses `ROW_NUMBER` to identify the records you want to retain:

```
SELECT NAME, ID, EMAIL, TYPE
FROM
(
    SELECT NAME, ID, EMAIL, TYPE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TYPE DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Follow up question now

So I am using the MS SQL Server Management Studio and I am using this example but now I'm being told "invalid column name". I know I'm connected correctly since I did a basic Select * From table and it recognized the columns then.  Is this an error that is common and has an obvious fix that I'm just missing?

Comment: @JessicaAncillotti This seems like a fairly different question from what you asked above.  You should mark one of these answers correct, and then ask a new question.  Most likely, there is a simple fix for your problem, but don't ask here.

Comment: Well, none of the answers are correct yet as none have done what was asked but I can ask a new question about the error in the examples provided to expand on them to make them answer the original question correctly.

Comment: @JessicaAncillotti My query with your sample data seems to be generating the output you expect.  I suggest that there is some other problem on your end, not necessarily related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want using aggregation:

```
select name, id, max(email) as email, max(type) as type
from tablename
group by name, id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `GROUP BY` and `JOIN`

```
select t1.*
from table_name t1
join (
  select id, max(type) max_type 
  from table_name
  group by id
) t2 on t1.id = t2.id and
        t1.type = t2.max_type
```